# Going from separate columns for each room to stacked columns with room variable as one column

Tags: python

I have a csv file with the following structure:
'Date,room 1, temperature 1, humidity 1, room 2, temperature 2, humidity 2,room 3 etc'
I want to easily process this data in python. My idea was to make a table where the rooms are all stacked into one column and have their corresponding temperature and humidity and date. So to simplify:
Go from this:

```
         Date   Room 1  Temperature 1   Room 2  Temperature 2
0  2024-01-13  bedroom             25  kitchen             23
1  2024-01-14  bedroom             26  kitchen             24
```

To this:

```
         Date     Room  Temperature
0  2024-01-13  bedroom             25
1  2024-01-14  bedroom             26
2  2024-01-13  kitchen             23
3  2024-01-14  kitchen             24
```

To make matters a bit more complex, halfway through my csv I go from 7 rooms to 10 rooms. Also, I don't want to assume that room 1 will always be bedroom, but I need there to be a consistent relation between the value in room and temperature/humidity, even if all of a sudden room 2 becomes "bedroom"

Tried looking some solutions online and chatGPT, which proposes using the melt function in python, but this does not deliver the result I am looking for. Any suggestions are welcome (feel free to also challenge my desired table format if you think there is an easier way to store this info)

Comment: "halfway through my csv I go from 7 rooms to 10 rooms", do you mean the number of columns increases after some records?

Comment: Hi, yes indeed, I go from 22 (1+ 3*7) to 31 (1+ 3*10).
To tell you the full story, I have an automation in home assistant that creates a csv file in the format I mentioned. After a few months I added new sensors to other rooms, so additional data was written to the csv lines